# What is AVAudioPlayer's averagePowerForChannel averaging?

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

The docs for `AVAudioPlayer` say `averagePowerForChannel:` "Returns the average power for a given channel, in decibels, for the sound being played." But it doesn't say what "average" means, or how/if that average is weighted. I'm particularly interested in what the range of samples is, specifically the time interval and whether it goes forward into the future at all.

[AVAudioRecorder: peak and average power](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240846/avaudiorecorder-peak-and-average-power) says that the formula used to calculate power is RMS (root mean square) over a number of samples, but also doesn't say how many samples are used.

*Optional bonus question*: if I want to calculate what the average power *will* be in, say, 100 msec -- enough time for an animation to begin now and reach an appropriate level soon -- what frameworks should I be looking into? [Confusion with meters in AVAudioRecorder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689774/confusion-with-meters-in-avaudiorecorder) says I can get ahold of the raw sample data with AudioQueue or RemoteIO, and then I can use something like this: [Android version of AVAudioPlayer's averagePowerForChannel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808899/android-version-of-avaudioplayers-averagepowerforchannel) -- but I haven't found sample code (pardon the pun).